# Can't find page_live.html.leex in my phoenix project folder

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I'm following this tutorial for a Phoenix live chat: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyg0FuSL5DY&t=280s. In the video the guy goes to a file called page_live.html.leex to edit the webpage content, but I can't seem to find the file in my own project folder. I have looked everywhere in my project directory.

I ran `mix phx.new --live --no-ecto chat` to create the project folder.

can anyone help me?

Comment: You prob installed recent phx and liveview which was undergoing some restructuring of files and structure since the video got released. `.leex` files are not used anymore. Have a lookaround in the readme of https://github.com/dwyl/phoenix-liveview-chat-example/tree/main to get an idea how its done these days.